# How to show my IP Address on Flask?

Tags: python, iframe, flask, jinja2

I'm have a problem to show my IP Address on Flask Python Web. Analogy, if in the PHP programming is very easy just use

`echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];`

but I don't know how to bring up the IP addresses in Python Flask Web.

Applications running on 192.168.43.46:4000, whereas I want to show:

```
<iframe id="form-iframe" src="http://192.168.43.46/vshell/index.php?type=services&clearcache=true" style="margin:0; width:100%; height:640px; border:none; overflow:hidden;" onload="AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()"></iframe>
```

scripts used in flask

```
<iframe id="form-iframe" src="{{ request.script_root }}/vshell/index.php?type=services&clearcache=true" style="margin:0; width:100%; height:640px; border:none; overflow:hidden;" onload="AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()"></iframe>
```

and which appeared on the client side browser:

how to show:

```
src="http://192.168.43.46/vshell/index.php?type=services&clearcache=true"
```

on Flask?

Comment: What does the browser see when you use `{{ request.script_root }}`?

Comment: `request.remote_addr`

Comment: browser see:
`{{ request.script_root }}` = `http://192.168.43.46:4000`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The request object has a [`.host`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.host) attribute, but that includes the port number, if available. To get just the host name or IP address, try:

```
{{ request.host.split(':')[0] }}
```

Alternatively, you could query the [WSGI environment](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.environ) directly:

```
{{ request.environ['SERVER_NAME'] }}
```

Comment: woow.... thanks @Robᵩ.

this work `src="http://{{ request.host.split(':')[0] }}/vshell/index.php?type=services&clearcache=true"`

Comment: `request.environ['SERVER_ADDR']` is the server IP address. SERVER_NAME is the domain name.